# Disable logging of Firebase Database with admin SDK node.js on GAE Flex

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have a node server with the Firebase Admin SDK running in the Google App Engine Flex environment. It runs really well. However, trying to find anything in the logs if you want to debug is a nightmare. The cloud logs are full of output like this. Streams of it. We are talking more than 10GB of logs in a few weeks, when only devs are hitting the server!

```
      sync: false,

      needReadable: true,

      emittedReadable: false,

      readableListening: false,

      resumeScheduled: false,

      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',

      data: [Function: socketOnData],

      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',

      '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],

      locals: {} } },

      connecting: false,

      _handle: [Object],

      domain: null,

      _pendingData: null,

      connecting: false,

      allowHalfOpen: true,

      _httpMessage: null },

      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',

      _readableState: [Object],
```

I figured it is DB logging. I can see many references in the minified code in node_modules. So I tried disabling with:

```
    app.database.enableLogging(false);
```

It makes no difference. Still full of logs. Interestingly when you run the server locally, I see none of these logs. Does anyone have any ideas? I'd like to

1. reduce the size of logs storage
2. not have filter everything and wait for the Google Cloud Logging
   interface to find actual output I want.

Comment: FWIW, on python the devserver does **not** display debug messages by default, so check your node devserver default log level and maybe set it so that all messages are displayed (as all of them are included in the GAE logs). Then you'll be able to modify the code to keep just the relevant logs and/or set the app's loglevel according to what you want to actually get logged.

Comment: Thanks @DanCornilescu - I have used the Python Standard runtime for many years. This is my first adventure into flex, where your app is built as a Docker image. There is no SDK as such. Thats what is odd. The same NodeJS code is running locally and I don't see all of this. I can see in the minified fireabase DB code loads of console.log so I guess it is that, but just not sure why it would run riot on the VM once deployed.

Comment: What is the log level of these messages? It may not be possible to disable the logs, but maybe you can raise the level of your app to "info" or higher and use the remaining levels in your app.

Comment: They are all info level in the Cloud logs, standard for a console.log I believe.   I guess I could try making all output from the app to be console.warn and filter on that, but it still doesn't stop the GB of log storage I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Closing this.

It turns out it wasn't Firebase, it was coming from express. Debug was added to a path I wasn't aware of and it was chucking out request object info like crazy.

I never saw this locally because I never worked with that path. I stumbled across it locally today.